# Put dates between sections in Beamer TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am giving a presentations over the course of two days.
My current code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=shaded]
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{TOC}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% Day 1

\section{1}

\section{2}

% Day 2

\section{3}

\section{4}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can show days in the TOC? Something like:

Day 1:

- Section 1
- Section 2

Day 2:

- Section 3
- Section 4

Comment: You could maybe just use `\section` for the days and `\subsection` for the actual sections, but `beamer` also supports `\part`s. See this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243530/47927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [current documentation of the `beamer` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) explains in section 10.3 how to use `\part`s which you could also use here (also, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243530/47927) for more information):

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=shaded]
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{TOC}
    Day 1:
    \tableofcontents[part=1]
    Day 2:
    \tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}

\part{Day 1}

\section{1}

\section{2}

\part{Day 2}

\section{3}

\section{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!