# Parts in Table of Contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I am unable to implement the solution regarding parts in table of contents, given in  answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243530/79682:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author Of Presentation}

\newcommand{\makepart}[1]{ % For convenience
\part{Title of part #1} \frame{\partpage}
\section{Section} \begin{frame} Section \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection} \begin{frame} Subsection \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection} \begin{frame} Subsection \end{frame}
\section{Section} \begin{frame} Section \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Part I:
\tableofcontents[part=1]
Part II:
\tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}

\makepart{1}

\makepart{2}

\end{document}
```

Can somebody give me an example of a document with: a) two parts ("part foo" and "part fee"), and b) different slides between each part ("Introduction of foo" and "Introduction of fee")?

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Can you clarify which problem you face with your code?

Comment: As you can see, frames in Part I and II are repeated in name, so I don't know how to differentiate them. For example, I want to know how to create section of part I, section of Part II, and so on (to make the difference in command explicitly). Did I explain well?

Comment: Can you make a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: Sure. I want to generate something where I am able to recognize the writings of every part explicitly. For example, slides that say "Section of Part I or II", and "Subsections of Part I or II", explicitly. I don't know where I can control the writings of every part, in order to make them appear. That's the reason I wrote "of Part I" and "of Part II" of every associated slide. I need an example of it. It is clear now?

Comment: is https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OQ4B.png what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I am looking for!

Comment: I would have never guessed that from the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `(sub-)section in toc` templates like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author Of Presentation}

\newcommand{\makepart}[1]{ % For convenience
\part{Title of part #1} \frame{\partpage}
\section{Section} \begin{frame} Section \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection} \begin{frame} Subsection \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection} \begin{frame} Subsection \end{frame}
\section{Section} \begin{frame} Section \end{frame}
}

\newcounter{mypart}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsection\ of part \themypart\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=1.5em\inserttocsubsection\ of part \themypart\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Part I: \addtocounter{mypart}{1}
\tableofcontents[part=1]
Part II: \addtocounter{mypart}{1}
\tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}

\makepart{1}

\makepart{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or if it should be free-form text and not just a number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author Of Presentation}

\newcommand{\makepart}[1]{ % For convenience
\part{Title of part #1} \frame{\partpage}
\section{Section} \begin{frame} Section \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection} \begin{frame} Subsection \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection} \begin{frame} Subsection \end{frame}
\section{Section} \begin{frame} Section \end{frame}
}

\def\currentpart{}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsection\ of \currentpart\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=1.5em\inserttocsubsection\ of \currentpart\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Part I: \def\currentpart{Part I}
\tableofcontents[part=1]
Part II: \def\currentpart{Part II}
\tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}

\makepart{1}

\makepart{2}

\end{document}
```